# Javascript API request: Issue with http request in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, httprequest, race-condition

Here's the request code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
    process(zips[i].zip);
}
```

This processes the data:

```
var process = function(zip) {
    var params = {
        host: 'api.openweathermap.org',
        path: '/data/2.5/weather/?apikey=key&zip=' + zip,
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var req = http.request(params, callback).end();
}
```

This also processes the data, final step:

```
var callback = function(response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(chunk).name);
    });
}
```

Now, the result is different all the time and not ordered:

> undefined Denver Kirkland New York City Chicago

or

> undefined Honolulu New York City Kirkland Denver

or

> undefined undefined New York City undefined Denver

Why is this happening? Is there a way to make this synchronous and make the `undefined` defined? Also, first is always `undefined`!

Please let me know if there's a better practice to achieve what I want, regardless how I am trying to.

Comment: Why do you think synchronicity is the problem with `undefined`?

Comment: @deceze, because it is always unordered

Comment: anyways, I would get by without ordering, but can't figure out why it has `undefined`

Comment: Are you sure that your array is zero-based and not 1-based?

Comment: @clarmond, yes. I know what you mean and updated as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the / in the path between ...weather and ?apikey=... such that it looks like:

```
path: '/data/2.5/weather?apikey=key&zip=' + zip
```

I tried hitting the endpoint with the path you provided from my browser and got 404s often, but not always. Removing that / gave me a valid response every time.

Comment: Miracle! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was getting 404'd too. But after stepping away from my computer for a minute and coming back the requests worked without changing any @SamKirklandWA code.

Based on [some forum posts](https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/search?q=rate) I think the free tier gets hammered pretty hard and causes issues from time to time.

Just wanted to add in case you start seeing undefined again.